# sed command bad option in substitution expression when replacing back slash

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am currently running the following command and getting a "bad option in substitution" error. What I would like to do is add a backslash to the string I am replacing but I am unable to do so. Any ideas?

Code:

```
 VAR="/host/test"
 echo ${VAR} | sed -e "s/\//\\\//g"
```

Comment: echo "${VAR}" | sed -e 's|/|//'g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use sed at all?

```
$ echo "${VAR//\//\\/}"
\/host\/test
```

It looks a bit horrible, but it works fine. See `${parameter/pattern/string}` in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion.

---

Your problem happens because you're using double quotes (`"`) around your sed code, not single quotes (`'`).

In double quotes, `\\` is interpreted as the escape sequence for a single `\`, so the code that sed ends up seeing is:

```
$ echo "s/\//\\\//g"
s/\//\\//g
#^  ^  ^
```

sed reads this as "search for `\/` and replace it by `\\`, with `/g` as options". This is an error because `/` is not a valid option.

Comment: thank you for your response! I tried your new solution, however, on my screen i still see /host/test any ideas why that could be? did i miss something? I did it exactly as you did

Comment: @paul590 Can you post a screenshot of your terminal with all the relevant commands?

Comment: thank you for your quick response, in terminal actually it works great! however I am running this command from a sh file and it doesnt seem to replace the characters with what i need this is a different issue thank you tho!!